# Cron job does not load a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web, hosting

I'm running a php page on the server with cron job. There is a function in the php page.

- The line `load('sonucal.php')` does not work. (main.php)
- The line `window.location.replace('main.php?abc='+def+'')` does not work. (sonucal.php)

This php page is working actively with cron job.

**main.php**

```
...
...

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function()
            {
            $('#fare').load('sonucal.php')
        },1000);
        });
    </script>
```

---

**sonucal.php**

```
echo "
...
...
window.location.replace('main.php?abc='+def+'');
</script>";
```

Comment: Cron doesn't run a in a web browser, so it doesn't process javascript (or HTML).

Answer (score -1):

You can not run a cronJob in a web browser. The cronJob are automated tasks that are run on a server, therefore every so often a window.location (?) will open.

Comment: main.php (this page given to scheduled task at the cron job )
`code`<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="trublans.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
setInterval(function(){
$('#fare').load('sonucal.php') 
 },1000);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
if(isset($_GET["gelen"]))
{.....}

</body></html>`code`
---
sonuclal.php
`code`echo"<script>
window.location.replace('main.php?gelen='+toplu+' ');
</script>";`code`
---
I'm trying to get the parameter with $_GET. Thank you..